# Outputting a standalone shell script from arguments

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I am solving an exercise. Essentially, it's a shell script that takes in file and/or directory arguments and outputs another (standalone) shell script that outputs these files, including any directory structure associated with them.

Example usage:

```
bundle.sh dir1 dir2 file1 file2 file3 >unpack.sh
```

This expects that *bundle.sh* can be found in the `PATH` environment variable. If not, just run it like this:

```
`pwd`/bundle.sh dir file1 file2 >unpack.sh
```

Running *unpack.sh* should recreate everything.

Accepted limitations:

- Only works for textual files
- Files may not contain the line **End of *filename***

Solution:

```
echo "# Run to unpack"
for i; do
    (cd $i 2>/dev/null &&
     echo "mkdir $i && cd $i" &&
     $0 * &&
     echo cd ..)
    cd $i 2>/dev/null || (
        echo echo `ls -l $i`
        echo "cat >$i <<'End of $i'"
        cat $i
        echo End of $i)
done
```

This is my solution for exercises 3-17 and 3-18 in the Unix Programming Environment by Brian W. Kernighan and Rob Pike. It works but I would appreciate any feedback. I will mention that the book has not yet covered conditional statements, globbing, etc. So I am trying to stick to what I've learned so far for now and might come back to it later.

One thing that I realize is that this doesn't deal with names that contain spaces. I have tried putting `\"`s around most `$i`s (except for the ones in the *echo*s, where it shouldn't matter) but that seems to make things worse. The other two is that I find my usage of *cd* to test for directories kind of a hack and the fact that I am not sure I am handling `$0` correctly, which is why I made explicit requirements on how to run *bundle.sh* (maybe there is some way to make it better?). However, I am not interested in just these issues, I want feedback in general given my requirements and constraints. Even advice regarding to style may be valuable to me.